# How to do a fake mouse wheel move in linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, x11, xlib

I'm trying to simulate keyboard and mouse events, i've successfully made fake keyboard keydown, keyup. Fake mouse button down, up and fake mouse move, but i don't found how to do fake mouse wheel move, can someone explain to me a simple way to do this in c++?

Mouse Move and Mouse button press:

```
Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
XTestFakeMotionEvent(dpy, -1, 50, 50, 0);
XTestFakeButtonEvent(dpy, Button1, true, 0);
XTestFakeButtonEvent(dpy, Button1, false, 0);
XFlush(dpy);
XCloseDisplay(dpy);
```

Keyboard key press:

```
Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
unsigned int keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, XK_Super_L);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dpy, keycode, true, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dpy, keycode, false, 0);
XFlush(dpy);
XCloseDisplay(dpy);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't a mousewheel step on Linux just another button press?  I can't test this for you now, but I recall on my system that rolling the mousewheel simply generated button events.  You can test this on your system by running the program `xev` which displays X input events.