# Faking mouse wheel scroll linux

Tags: c++, scroll, mouseevent, mousewheel

I try to fake a mouse wheel scroll with c++ in linux, i already can fake left, right and wheel click with:

```
XTestFakeButtonEvent(display_p_m, 1, True, CurrentTime);
```

But i can't find anything to fake the scrolling action, i already try to change the second argument of XTestFakeButtonEvent as said here : [relative Stackoverflow subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793338/how-to-do-a-fake-mouse-wheel-move-in-linux)

So, how to achieve that effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a fake mouse wheel move in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793338/how-to-do-a-fake-mouse-wheel-move-in-linux)

Comment: @JonathanPotter I already refer to this topic with my link.

Comment: Isn't "wheel scrolling" just sending one or more mousewheel ("button/click") events? Is there any other type of wheel scrolling?